# little-oh notation

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, asymptotics, definition

Assume I have a function $ f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^n $, and let $ h\in \mathbb{R}^m $.

Does the notation $ f\left(x_0+h\right)=o\left(h\right) $ (for fixed $x_0 $)
mean that
$$ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{||f\left(x_{0}+h\right)||_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}}{||h||_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}}=0 ?$$

Because I've seen in a few places that lecturers wrote just $ \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x_{0}+h\right)}{||h||}=0 $, which doesn't make any sense to me. I'll be glad for a clarification. What's the acceptable definition worldwide? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Writing

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(x_{0}+h\right)}{||h||_{\mathbb R^m}}=0$$  does make sense. For $h \neq 0$, the map $g(h) = \frac{f(x_0+h)}{\Vert h \Vert_{\mathbb R^m}}$ is well defined. Stating that its limit is equal to $0$ means that

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left\Vert \frac{f(x_0+h)}{\Vert h \Vert_{\mathbb R^m}} - 0\right\Vert_{\mathbb R^n} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \left\Vert \frac{f(x_0+h)}{\Vert h \Vert_{\mathbb R^m}} \right\Vert_{\mathbb R^n} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0}  \frac{\Vert f(x_0+h) \Vert_{\mathbb R^n}}{\Vert h \Vert_{\mathbb R^M}}=0.$$

So the two definitions are indeed equivalent.

Comment: I think you switched m and n in the last one

Comment: Well spotted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would never say $f(x_0 + h) = o(h)$ when $f$ has values in $\mathbb R^n$ rather than $\mathbb R$.

But if I were going to say it, it would mean one of the two limits you wrote. Those limits are equivalent: $\frac{f(x_0 + h)}{\|h\|} \to 0$ (that is, $0 \in \mathbb R^n$) exactly when $\frac{\|f(x_0 + h)\|}{\|h\|} \to 0$ (that is, $0 \in \mathbb R$).

That's because the definition of a limit in $\mathbb R^n$ means that the first of these limits holds if and only if $\left\|\frac{f(x_0 + h)}{\|h\|} - 0\right\| \to 0$, and this simplifies to the second limit.

Comment: A good notation, in my opinion, would be $f(x_0+h) = o\left(\|h\|\right)$

Comment: Or even $\|f(x_0 + h)\| = o(\|h\|)$. Although we can make sense of less intuitive notation, it is often expected for a statement $f(x) = o(g(x))$ that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the same *type* of object.

Comment: I think it's okay to omit the $\|\cdot\|$. Here's a more general definition I've seen for little-o notation, for real-valued $f$ and $g$: Write $f(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to L$ (with $L$ possibly infinite) if, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|f(x)| \le \varepsilon |g(x)|$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $L$. So we don't care about sign, and having $g(x) = 0$ for some $x$ doesn't break the definition. Also, it extends to $f$ and $g$ taking values in an arbitrary normed space (and $x$ in an arbitrary topological space: e.g., $x \in \mathbb N \cup \{\infty\} $ and $L = \infty$.)

Comment: To me, $f(x) = o_a(g(x))$ is defined when $g$ is a nonnegative function and means $\|f(x)\| \leqslant \varepsilon(x) \times g(x) $ with $\varepsilon$ a nonnegative function with $\varepsilon(x) \to_{x\to a} 0$. I agree that this can appear weird because $f$ and $g$ are not of the same type, but if we try to always apply this definition, there is no ambiguity

Comment: Why would you never use that notation? As I understand its actually acceptable, for example in the book "Mathematical Analysis 1 " Vladimir A.Zorich defines $ f=o\left(g\right),\thinspace\thinspace when\,\,x\to x_{0}\,\,\,\,\iff\,\,\,||f\left(x\right)||_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}=o\left(||g\left(x\right)||_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\right)\thinspace\thinspace when\thinspace\thinspace x\to x_{0} $

Comment: It technically works, but it looks weird and can confuse people.